# GridBagLayout not working in JTabbedPane

Tags: java

I have an issue with re-positioning buttons, fields and labels in my JTabs with GridBagLayout. I am unsure of how to re-position within my JTabs. The buttons and such show but they all display in a single line rather than taking the constraints I have set to them.

I want to implement the layout in the first image into the second one within a JTabbedPane, as you can see when I use JTabs everything stays in a single line.

[Before implementing JTabbedPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W65t.png)

[After implementing JTabbedPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNgcT.png)

I have attached a part of the code below:

```
private void programProperties() {

        reStockButton.addActionListener(this);
        sellButton.addActionListener(this);
        setPriceButton.addActionListener(this);
        getNameButton.addActionListener(this);
        getStockLevelButton.addActionListener(this);
        getPriceButton.addActionListener(this);

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(menuTabs, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5), 0, 0));
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        menuTabs.add("Description", productDescription);
        menuTabs.add("Sale", productSale);
        menuTabs.add("Restock", productRestock);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productRestock.add(reStockLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productSale.add(sellLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productDescription.add(setPriceLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productDescription.add(getNameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productDescription.add(getStockLevelLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        productDescription.add(getPriceLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        productDescription.add(reStockField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 2; 
        productSale.add(sellField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        productRestock.add(setPriceField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        productDescription.add(getNameField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        productDescription.add(getStockLevelField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        productDescription.add(getPriceField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productRestock.add(reStockButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productSale.add(sellButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productDescription.add(setPriceButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productDescription.add(getNameButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productDescription.add(getStockLevelButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        productDescription.add(getPriceButton, gbc);



        menuBar();
        frame.setTitle("Program");
        frame.setSize(750,300);
        frame.setLocation(500,300);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a Component can only have one parent. You are adding your labels twice, which has the effect of only adding the label to the second Container.

Second, you haven't included the gbc argument in all of your adds, as demonstrated below

```
        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(getPriceLabel, gbc);
        productDescription.add(getPriceLabel);
```

### Edit

I believe your problem is where you are calling

```
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

You should be calling `productDescription.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` instead / as well.

Comment: If I remove one of them I still get the same result. The gbc doesn't apply within the JTabbedPane.

Comment: I've updated the code according to your comment. I still get all the adds in a straight line.

Comment: Yes! productDescription.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); solves the issue completely. I was assuming setting a new GridBagLayout for the panel would fix the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LeventAkyildiz Great! Please click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that my answer solved this problem